# Scala version not updating

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10, scala-2.11

My project used Scala version 2.10.2. I am trying to update to 2.11.4. I have updated my `build.sbt`.

But now when I run `sbt compile` it still shows me `Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2 ...`. I believe it means that my Scala version hasn't been updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @m-z so how can I find out what scala version the project is using without checking the build.sbt file? is there a command like sbt --scala-version?

Comment: You can build your project and see under which folder the binaries are generated `target/scala-X.Y/...`.

Comment: @vptheron scala is not updating. It is showing scala-2.10

Comment: Don't just say "I have updated my build.sbt" — show us exactly what you put there.

Comment: `show scalaVersion` is how to tell what Scala version you're building for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `show` to see the value of any setting:

```
% sbt
[info] Loading project definition from ...
[info] Set current project to ...
> show scalaVersion
[info] 2.12.0-M1
```

`scalaVersion` tells you which Scala version your project is built with. You can also verify it using `console`:

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.12.0-M1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> scala.util.Properties.versionString
res0: String = version 2.12.0-M1
```

This may be different from the Scala version used to compile your build definition. sbt 0.13 always uses Scala 2.10 for that:

```
> eval scala.util.Properties.versionString
[info] ans: String = version 2.10.4
```

You can't change that; it's determined by the sbt version.